# Run repeating function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a label blink forever. Simplified version of my code:

```swift
func blink (label: UILabel) -> Void {

    let text = label.text
    label.text = ""
    sleep(1)
    label.text = text
    sleep(2)
    print("blinking")
    blink(label: label)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label = getLabel()
    blink(label: label)
}
```

The view never loads, because its waiting for the Blink function to finish, which it never does. How can I make this function work, but not wait for it to complete itself (witch it never will) before the rest of my code can run?

Comment: I would try a simple timer

Comment: You need to do all waiting off the main thread, and only using the main thread momentarily to run UI updates. Otherwise, (as you've noticed), you block your main thread and nothing else happens in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run a timer, with a 1 second interval, which will repeat. Just invalidate the timer if you don't want to use it anymore. Ideally call it when the controller is deinitialized.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                blink(label: label)
            }
```

Also instead of using sleep... try using UIView like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            //do animtions
        }) { (completed) in
            // repeat or finish
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is handy to have a separate class for this action, to ensure you will not have some concurrency and memory allocation problems

So you can create some class like this one

```
class Blink {
    typealias BlinkBlock = (Bool) -> ()

    private var timer: Timer?
    private let interval: TimeInterval
    private let blinkBlock: BlinkBlock
    private var blinkState: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.blinkBlock(self.blinkState)
            }
        }
    }

    init(interval: TimeInterval, blinkBlock: @escaping BlinkBlock) {
        self.blinkBlock = blinkBlock
        self.interval = interval
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func startBlinking() {
        stopBlinking()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(onTimer),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)

        blinkState = true
    }

    func stopBlinking() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    @objc
    func onTimer() {
        blinkState = !blinkState
    }
}
```

and then in your view controller just

```
var blink: Blink?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let text = label.text
    blink = blink(interval: 1) {
        label.text = $0 ? text : ""
        print("blinking")
    }

    blink?.startBlinking()
}
```

This will not block main thread and will safely invalidate timer on deallocation

Answer (score 0):

You should create class inherited form UILabel. After that you create function repeat reply on timer. Please follow the code:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    var timer: Timer?
    var counter = 0

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.fireTimer()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.fireTimer()
    }

    func fireTimer(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector:  #selector(waittingAnimation),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func waittingAnimation(){
        self.isHidden = !(self.isHidden)
    }
}
```

in your viewcontroller you call fireTimer() to execute animation

```
@IBOutlet weak var customLabel: CustomLabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.customLabel.text = "ABC"
    self.customLabel.fireTimer()
}
```